# Creating "rules" for adding new enum values to enum

Tags: java, enums

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to create rules that are checked at compile time when developers add new enum values to an enum.

**Example**:

```
public enum Execution {
    TAKS_N("parallel"),
    TASK_A("sequential"),
    TASK_D("sequential")
}
```

Is there a way to prevent a developer to add a value to this enum with the parameter `"parallel"` if there has already been a sequential task before?

```
public enum Execution {
    TAKS_N("parallel"),
    TASK_ALLOWED("parallel"), // this is allowed
    TASK_A("sequential"),
    TASK_D("sequential"),
    TASK_NOT_ALLOWED("parallel") // this is a no no
}
```

My current solution is, to add a comment to the enum with rules for how to add new values and create a dedicated Unit Test for validating the enum.

Comment: That looks like the sort of thing you could write a custom lint rule for.

Comment: Can you provide additional information about lint rules? I had a quick look, but not sure if this is really viable. Are lint rules limited to specific IDEAs?

Comment: I'm more familiar with linting Typescript than Java. But linting is a process that lets you run additional checks on your code. It integrates with IDEs and you also normally build the checks into your build pipeline so the build fails if it doesn't pass your lint rules. The devs at work use SonarLint and SonarQube so that might be a place to start looking.